# Build HDF5 library on MIPS32

Tags: cmake, cross-platform, mips, hdf5, mips32

I try build hdf5 library for Mips32 using CMAKE and appropriate Toolchainfile for mips. I get information below:

```
-- Check size of __float128
-- Check size of __float128 - failed
CMake Error: TRY_RUN() invoked in cross-compiling mode, please set the following cache variables appropriately:
   H5_LDOUBLE_TO_LONG_SPECIAL_RUN (advanced)
   H5_LDOUBLE_TO_LONG_SPECIAL_RUN__TRYRUN_OUTPUT (advanced)
For details see /home/dkol/GitRepository/build/HDF5-prefix/src/HDF5-build/TryRunResults.cmake
-- Checking IF your system converts long double to (unsigned) long values with special algorithm... no
CMake Error: TRY_RUN() invoked in cross-compiling mode, please set the following cache variables appropriately:
   H5_LONG_TO_LDOUBLE_SPECIAL_RUN (advanced)
   H5_LONG_TO_LDOUBLE_SPECIAL_RUN__TRYRUN_OUTPUT (advanced)
For details see /home/dkol/GitRepository/build/HDF5-prefix/src/HDF5-build/TryRunResults.cmake
-- Checking IF your system can convert (unsigned) long to long double values with special algorithm... no
CMake Error: TRY_RUN() invoked in cross-compiling mode, please set the following cache variables appropriately:
   H5_LDOUBLE_TO_LLONG_ACCURATE_RUN (advanced)
   H5_LDOUBLE_TO_LLONG_ACCURATE_RUN__TRYRUN_OUTPUT (advanced)
For details see /home/dkol/GitRepository/build/HDF5-prefix/src/HDF5-build/TryRunResults.cmake
-- Checking IF correctly converting long double to (unsigned) long long values... no
CMake Error: TRY_RUN() invoked in cross-compiling mode, please set the following cache variables appropriately:
   H5_LLONG_TO_LDOUBLE_CORRECT_RUN (advanced)
   H5_LLONG_TO_LDOUBLE_CORRECT_RUN__TRYRUN_OUTPUT (advanced)
For details see /home/dkol/GitRepository/build/HDF5-prefix/src/HDF5-build/TryRunResults.cmake
-- Checking IF correctly converting (unsigned) long long to long double values... no
CMake Error: TRY_RUN() invoked in cross-compiling mode, please set the following cache variables appropriately:
   H5_NO_ALIGNMENT_RESTRICTIONS_RUN (advanced)
   H5_NO_ALIGNMENT_RESTRICTIONS_RUN__TRYRUN_OUTPUT (advanced)
For details see /home/dkol/GitRepository/build/HDF5-prefix/src/HDF5-build/TryRunResults.cmake
-- Checking IF alignment restrictions are strictly enforced... no
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/dkol/GitRepository/build/HDF5-prefix/src/HDF5-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/dkol/GitRepository/build/HDF5-prefix/src/HDF5-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

How can i fix this error?

Comment: You need manually set each of the `H5_*` variables to the correct values for your MIPS target because you are cross compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's problem with failure of cross-compiling supporting [HDF5 Issue](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/faq/compile.html)